# Google drive api v3 to create multiple copies in the same request to drive services in C#

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I have the following code where I make three separate calls to Google Drive service to create three copies of a google doc. This code takes a while to run (almost 10 seconds). I wonder if there is a method to create multiple copies at once?

```
 public Tuple<string, string, string> CopySubmission(string fileId, string newFileName, string targetFolderId)
    {
        try
        {
            var _driveService = GetDriveServiceInstance();

            Permission newPermission = new Permission();

            File readOnlyFile = new File();
            readOnlyFile.Name = newFileName.Replace(' ', '-') + "_assess";
            readOnlyFile.Parents = new List<string> { targetFolderId };
            string readOnlyFileId = _driveService.Files.Copy(readOnlyFile, fileId).Execute().Id;
            newPermission.Type = "anyone";
            newPermission.Role = "reader";
            _driveService.Permissions.Create(newPermission, readOnlyFileId).Execute();


            File dialogueFile = new File();
            dialogueFile.Name = newFileName.Replace(' ', '-') + "_feedback";
            dialogueFile.Parents = new List<string> { targetFolderId };
            string dialogueFileId = _driveService.Files.Copy(dialogueFile, fileId).Execute().Id;
            newPermission.Type = "anyone";
            newPermission.Role = "commenter";
            _driveService.Permissions.Create(newPermission, dialogueFileId).Execute();

            File reviseFile = new File();
            reviseFile.Name = newFileName.Replace(' ', '-') + "_revise";
            reviseFile.Parents = new List<string> { targetFolderId };
            string reviseFileId = _driveService.Files.Copy(reviseFile, fileId).Execute().Id;
            newPermission.Type = "anyone";
            newPermission.Role = "writer";
            _driveService.Permissions.Create(newPermission, reviseFileId).Execute();

            return Tuple.Create(readOnlyFileId, dialogueFileId, reviseFileId);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: I've never used google drive api before but it seems you can [batch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch) multiple drive api requests. Hope it works for you.